# GWT eclipse : errors/warnings preferences

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Is there a possibility to change GWT errors/warnings preferences without using the eclipse UI ? Are these preferences stored anywhere or can I overwrite them somehow using the preference files in .settings directory ?

Best Regards,

Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I've managed to find the setting on my own. In the global eclipse preferences there is a property called com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite/problemSeverities . You can check how to set it by exporting all the eclipse preferences after some changes made in UI. In my case I needed to change it to:

com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite/problemSeverities=com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.uibinder.problems.UiBinderTemplateProblemType#401\=1

Thanks for your responses,

Jake

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the GWT compiler's log level setting then [it can be set from the command line](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging?hl=en#enabling_internal_debug).

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't mean the GWT compiler log level but the GWT errors/warnings preferences in eclipse - you can access them through Window -> Preferences -> Google -> Errors/Warnings

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question on the [GPE user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-plugin-eclipse).